# edit text in grid view in android with xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, gtk#, xamarin-studio

hi friends iam using xamarin with c# for mobile application.in grid view one edit text is there.when enter the number and click on back button the values is not visbled means page is refreshing.how to solve the problem

```
    public override Android.Views.View GetView(int position, Android.Views.View convertView, Android.Views.ViewGroup parent)
    {

        int row = GetRow(position);
        var item = PositionToString(position);
        var txtName = convertView as TextView ?? new TextView(context);

        if (row == 0)
        {
            txtName.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.textview2);
            txtName.SetHeight(40);
            txtName.SetText(item, TextView.BufferType.Normal);
            txtName.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Black);

        }
        else
        {
            txtName.SetText(item, TextView.BufferType.Normal);
            txtName.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Black);
            txtName.SetHeight(40);
            txtName.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.textview1);
        }
        if (position % 3 == 2)
        {
            if (row == 0)
            {

                txtName = convertView as TextView ?? new TextView(context);
                txtName.SetHeight(40);

                txtName.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Black);
                txtName.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.textview2);                   
            }
            else
            {

                txtName = convertView as EditText ?? new EditText(context);
                txtName.SetHeight(40);
                txtName.SetText(item, EditText.BufferType.Normal);
               txtName.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.grideditextbackground);
               txtName.InputType = Android.Text.InputTypes.ClassNumber;


            }
        }

        return txtName;
    }
}
```

}